# Is there a way to create a line separator using a Label object in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using VS 2010.

Is there a way to make a line separator in C# Windows Forms? I sometimes use default background color and total white background.

Both of this methods I found does not work for me.

```
        label2.AutoSize = false;
        label2.Height = 2;
        label2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
```

or

```
        label2.MaximumSize = new Size(100, 0);
        label2.AutoSize = true;
```

Comment: It's been marked duplicate but i wasn't able to find it at first glance, also the previous title does not specify something about line separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the first one to use `BorderStyle.FixedSingle` or change the height to at least `4`.

There's not a lot that's new in WinForms, but VS should come with the [Visual Basic Power Packs Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488277.aspx). If you see that section in your toolbox, there's a line control available that you can drop on your designer. You can change its border style, thickness, color, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just wish VB developers would invest on making a line object available on toolbox with prepared editable properties.